# Node is not deleting from cordite dashboard

Tags: corda, nms, cordite

How to delete node from cordite dashboard ? Delete alert shows but when i clicked on delete button nothing happened. Also i have tried through swagger. Currently m using virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

there is an old UI bug that doesn't capture the event when clicking directly on the icon.

To work around the issue, you can click just to the top-right of the icon. Here is a video of explaining it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NczNdVxEZyM

We hope to have greater priortisation to fix this issue and to provide a more reactive and smooth experience.

Btw, you can also always code directly to the swagger api on `/swagger`.

Comment: Not worked. I have tried through swagger with valid token but it always shows bad request with valid token.

Comment: I've tried the swagger using the latest version, v0.4.5, available here: https://hub.docker.com/r/cordite/network-map. I assume you shut down the node itself, and no other node is advertising the same name.